# Sequelize support for ~ operator with postgres ltree queries

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, ltree

I have a simple postgres ltree query

```
select * from data_objects WHERE path ~ 'root.*{1}';
```

I would like to implement this in sequelize, but there is no mapping for the ~ operator.

Is it possible to override the mappings? or do I have to use a raw sql query?

Comment: You can use `regexp_matches()` instead.

Comment: If sequelize does not support database-specific functions, then you might be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff that put me on the right path. I've added answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution:

```
params.path = {
        $regexp:'root.*{1}'
};
```

Which translates as

```
where "path" ~ 'root.*{1}'
```

I hadn't seen the $regexp operator

Comment: I'm curious: What would `$regexp` do if you were using SQLIte or SQL Server?  These databases don't have any native support for regex like.  I think this answer still has a caveat that you are running Postgres.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen $regexp is only supported for MySQL/PG. In any event, the ltree implementation is specific to Postgres. If I change db down the line I'll be looking at a new architecture - so hopefully that doesn't happen :)

Answer (score 1):

If you ran your query as a raw query using sequelize, it should work:

```
sequelize.query("select * from data_objects WHERE path ~ 'root.*{1}'",
                { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(users => {

    })
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html) for more information.  Note that by using a native query you are introducing a hard dependency on Postgres into your Node code.  Whether you choose to do this depends on you.

Perhaps you could also rephrase your query using `LIKE`:

```
select * from data_objects WHERE LOWER(path) LIKE 'root%{1}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid raw queries. I've found regex will do the job.